# One-hot encoding Tensorflow Strings

Tags: tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I have a list of strings as labels for training a neural network. Now I want to convert them via one_hot encoding so that I can use them for my tensorflow network.
My input list looks like this:

```
 labels = ['"car"', '"pedestrian"', '"car"', '"truck"', '"car"']
```

The requested outcome should be something like

```
 one_hot [0,1,0,2,0]
```

What is the easiest way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Andi

Comment: Your output is not **one hot** encoding. It's a simple string to index. Take a look at `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()` probably.

Comment: This is not one hot encoding. You have the wrong concept

Answer (score 0):

the desired outcome looks like LabelEncoder in sklearn, not like OneHotEncoder - in tf you need [CategoryEncoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/CategoryEncoding) - BUT it is *A preprocessing layer which encodes integer features*.:

```
inp = layers.Input(shape=[X.shape[0]])
x0 = layers.CategoryEncoding(
          num_tokens=3, output_mode="multi_hot")(inp)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[x0])
model.compile(optimizer= 'adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy()])
print(model.summary())
```

- this part gets encoding of unique values... And you can make another branch in this model to input your initial vector & fit it according labels from this reference-branch (it is like join reference-table with fact-table in any database) -- here will be ensemble of referenced-data & your needed data & output...

pay attention to -- *num_tokens=3, output_mode="multi_hot"* -- are being given explicitly... AND numbers from class_names get apriory to model use, as is **Feature Engineering** - like this (in pd.DataFrame)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'transport_col':['"car"', '"pedestrian"', '"car"', '"truck"', '"car"']}
dataset_df =  pd.DataFrame(data=d)

classes = dataset_df['transport_col'].unique().tolist()
print(f"Label classes: {classes}")

df= dataset_df['transport_col'].map(classes.index).copy()
print(df)
```

*from [manual example](https://tensorflow.google.cn/decision_forests/tutorials/beginner_colab)* **REF:** Encode the categorical label into an integer.
**Details:** This stage is necessary if your classification label is represented as a string. Note: Keras expected classification labels to be integers.

Answer (score 0):

in another architecture, perhaps, you could use [StringLookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/StringLookup)

```
vocab= np.array(np.unique(labels))
inp = tf.keras.Input(shape= labels.shape[0], dtype=tf.string)
x = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)(inp)
```

but labels are dependent vars usually, as opposed to features, and shouldn't be used at Input

[Everything in keras.docs](https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/)

possible FULL CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras

X = np.array([['"car"', '"pedestrian"', '"car"', '"truck"', '"car"']])
vocab= np.unique(X)
print(vocab)

y=  np.array([[0,1,0,2,0]])

inp = layers.Input(shape=[X.shape[0]], dtype='string')
x0= tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab, name='finish')(inp)    

model = keras.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[x0])
model.compile(optimizer= 'adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.categorical_crossentropy])
print(model.summary())

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
for layerIndex, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    print(layerIndex)
    func = K.function([model.get_layer(index=0).input], layer.output)
    layerOutput = func([X])  # input_data is a numpy array
    print(layerOutput)
    if layerIndex==1:   # the last layer here
      scale = lambda x: x - 1 
      print(scale(layerOutput))
```

res:

> [[0 1 0 2 0]]

Answer (score 0):

another possible Solution for your case - [layers.TextVectorization](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/core_preprocessing_layers/text_vectorization/)

```
import numpy as np
import keras

input_array = np.atleast_2d(np.array(['"car"', '"pedestrian"', '"car"', '"truck"', '"car"']))
vocab= np.unique(input_array)

input_data = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='string') 
layer = layers.TextVectorization( max_tokens=None, standardize=None, split=None, output_mode="int",  vocabulary=vocab) 

int_data = layer(input_data) 
model = keras.Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=int_data)

output_dataset = model.predict(input_array)
print(output_dataset) # starts from 2 ... probably [0, 1] somehow concerns binarization ?

scale = lambda x: x - 2 
print(scale(output_dataset))
```

result:

> array([[0, 1, 0, 2, 0]])